# Javascript open new window, need to stop from loading in same

Tags: javascript

Ok so im working on a bingo site that has a games page and a bingo rooms page.  I need the players to be able to simultaneously play the casino games while playing bingo games.

Whats happening is everything just loads in same window.

At the moment for example i have on the onclick event as follows...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Player.LaunchBingoRoom('169')">
```

the LaunchBingoRoom i have:

```
LaunchBingoRoom: function (roomId) {
        if (!Player.IsLoggedIn()) {
            window.location.href = 'loginpage.html?login2play';
            return;
        }
        var roomFound = false;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(Player.BingoRooms(), function (roomInstance) {
            var bingoRoomId = roomInstance.RoomId();
            if (bingoRoomId.toLowerCase() == roomId.toLowerCase()) {
                roomFound = true;
                Game.OpenBingoRoomWindow(roomId, 100, 100);
                return;
            }
        });
```

how will i put the open.window in?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

here it is, sorry bout that.

```
 OpenBingoRoomWindow: function (roomId, left, top) {
        var session = Game.SessionDetails();
        if (session == undefined) {
            return false;
        }
        window.open(((document.location.protocol == 'https:') ? 'https://' : 'http://') + this.BaseUrl + '/launch/bingo/' + roomId + '/' + session.UserId + '/' + session.SessionId + '/' + session.JSessionId + '/' + session.Language, "BingoRoom", "width=800,height=600,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ",toolbar=0,status=0,location=no,");
        return true;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

top open in new window, use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open), change:

```
window.location.href = 'loginpage.html?login2play';
```

to

```
window.open('loginpage.html?login2play');
```

Comment: He thanks for answering so soon, appreciate but would that not be just to open the loginpage.html in new window. I need the game to open in new window if that makes sense.

Comment: _"I need the game to open in new window if that makes sense"_ - So take the code that Sudhir has provided, i.e., the `window.open(...)`, and use it anywhere that you need to open a window.

Comment: I dont have a OpenBingoRoomWindow function, but  i have:     GetBingoRooms: function () {
        var result = Game.BingoRooms();
        if (result != undefined) {
            for (var i in result.Rooms) {
                var room = result.Rooms[i];
                Player.BingoRooms.push(new BingoRoom(room));
            }
        }
    },

Comment: You _do_ have an `OpenBingoRoomWindow()` function, the code in your question refers to it...